# Testing Linux shell script in or from Windows environment, without jumping from window to windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash

I'm usually using VM/linux to run scripts, copying script using putty
or writing them directly there, but some times too many opened windows is not that comfortable..

I was recently trying to run shell script, using  RUN option in Notepad++
to use build in Ubuntu in win10 anniversary, but can't really manage to get the right syntax to do it.. and didn't find any plugin to do so..
I would appreciate if anyone can put me to the right path in this one.

I found that it is also possible to do it using sygwin, by `C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "command.sh"`  but again its an extra software piece... and bit far from natural Linux environment, and slight different paths etc..

there is also a solutions to run some shell IDE using X11 using Xming, to work with Linux VM without switching between the opened windows. but in this case Question is the where can I find a proper shell IDE for linux, capable to run shell scripts directly from it, without living the IDE window, like all other IDE's do ?

any real solution would be appreciated.

Comment: *Any* programmer's editor -- emacs, vim, atom, all of them -- can transfer a file to a remote system when saved. Likewise, *any* programmer's editor can run an arbitrary build/test command, including one that runs a command on that remote system. You don't need some kind of fancy-pants "IDE" to meet that need (and us old-hat Unix types tend to be a little contemptuous of them as a breed -- your language needing an IDE to let folks work effectively in it tends to mean your language has way too much boilerplate).

Answer (score 0):

It will NOT replace a pure Linux environment but, it is a closest I've seen

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php